# I can't generate \label{fig:mwe-plot} with knitr

Tags: r, markdown, knitr, pandoc

I am having trouble generating `\label{}` for plots when using knitr to go from a `*.Rmd` file to a `*.md` file via `knitr`; and then converting to `*.pdf` via `pandoc`.

An MWE for my `*.Rmd`is included below:

````
```{r Setup, include=FALSE, results="hide", warning=FALSE}
opts_chunk$set(dev="cairo_pdf", fig.lp="fig:", echo=FALSE, results="hide", 
               message=FALSE, warning=FALSE)
```

```{r mwe-plot, fig.cap = "MWE plot."}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) +
  geom_bar() 
```
````

I knit:

```
knit("mwe.Rmd")
```

Then I use pandoc

```
pandoc -o mwe.pdf mwe.md
```

I should be able to cross-reference the plot with `Figure \ref{fig:mwe-plot}` in my `*.Rmd` source. But it seems that the `\label{fig:mwe-plot}` hasn't been created in `mwe.tex` if I run:

```
pandoc -o mwe.pdf mwe.md
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The issue is that you are writing a R markdown file and the options related to LaTeX don't work (they have no effect) in such documents. `fig.cap` works, but `fig.lp` won't and you won't get any `\label{}` added at all because the output hook for Rmd documents is markdown and in general there is no label etc there.

In this case you need to write the `\label{}` manually in `fig.cap` as if you were adding this explicitly in a LaTeX document. For example:

````
```{r mwe-plot, fig.cap = "\\label{fig:mwe-plot}MWE plot."}
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl))) +
  geom_bar()
```
````

Now knitr will dump that caption verbatim into the markdown file using the markdown image markup conventions (we need to escape the backslash when entering the string in R, hence the `\\` in the `fig.cap` argument). Pandoc will then be able to work with this caption and the label and the references to it should all resolve themselves.

The other option is more complicated; there is nothing stopping you from writing your own custom hooks to do this for you, but you'll have to study the LaTeX hook and the MD hook to see how to combine elements of both that you need.

Note that this issue (chunk options that pertain to LaTeX outputs) applies to all such chunk options when writing an Rmd file. This is sort of implied in the Options page of the KNitr website but it still caught me by surprise when I first started using Knitr with markdown and using pandoc to render.

Comment: Thanks! I have been hoping to work on "the other option" you mentioned and I just have not found time for it yet :)

Comment: I believe that my question is relevant to your answer (it's a bit different though, as I explicitly generate labels for cross-referencing as a part of dynamic chunk generation). Would love to hear from you, Gavin, and/or @Yihui about this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26883864/2872891. Thanks!

Comment: @GavinSimpson, please, how do you afterwards cross-reference the figure? I tried to call chunk name `\@ref{mwe-plot}` in my text like ''Look at figure `\@ref{mwe-plot}`'' but it prints it in a same way, does not correctly add the figure number. I am using `output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rticles::elsevier_article`.  Thank you

Comment: @maycca, just use the raw LaTeX code `\ref{mwe-plot}` directly.