# knitr templating - Dynamic chunks issue

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc, r-markdown, reproducible-research

The following code is a very simplified *MRE* for an issue I'm experiencing. I'm trying to avoid `R` template packages, such as `brew`, and only use `knit_expand()` to achieve my goals. The **issue** is twofold:

1. generated chunks don't get parsed (this is not happening in my real code, but happens in MRE)
2. instead of LaTeX `\includegraphics`, `knitr` (or `rmarkdown`, or `pandoc`) generates RMarkdown syntax for inserting figures (`![]`).

In regard to the former, I have a feeling that it might be related to my incorrect use of `get()` or its argument. Your advice would be very much appreciated. The **MRE** follows ('.Rmd' document):

````
---
title: "MRE: a dynamic chunk issue"
author: "Aleksandr Blekh"
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    keep_tex: yes
    highlight: NULL
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)

opts_knit$set(progress = F, verbose = F)
opts_chunk$set(comment=NA, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE, tidy=FALSE)
```

```{r Preparation, results='hide'}

g1 <- plot(cars)
g2 <- plot(iris$Sepal.Length)

myPlots <- list(g1, g2)

bcRefStr <- list("objType" = "fig",
                 "objs" = c("g1", "g2"),
                 "str" = "Plots \\ref{fig:g1} and \\ref{fig:g2}")
```

```{r DynamicChunk, include=FALSE}
chunkName <- "{{name}}"
chunkHeader <- paste0("```{r ", chunkName, ", ")
chunkOptions <- "include=TRUE, results='asis', fig.height=4, fig.width=4, fig.cap='{{name}}'"
chunkHeaderFull <- paste0(chunkHeader, chunkOptions, "}")
chunkBody <- "print(get('{{name}}'))"

latexFigEnvBegin <- "cat('\\\\begin{figure}')"
latexFigEnvEnd <- "cat('\\\\end{figure}')"
latexFigCenter <- "cat('\\\\centering')"

latexObjLabel <- paste0("cat('\\\\caption{\\\\ ", "{{name}}\\\\label{", bcRefStr$objType, ":{{name}}", "}}')")

chunkText <- c(chunkHeaderFull,
               latexFigEnvBegin, latexFigCenter,
               chunkBody,
               latexObjLabel, latexFigEnvEnd,
               "```", "\n")

figReportParts <- lapply(bcRefStr$objs, function (x) knit_expand(text = chunkText, name = x))
```

`r knit(text = unlist(figReportParts))`
````

Comment: @Andrie: Thank you for editing my question. I was too concerned about the issue per se that overlooked improving the question's readability.

Comment: Can you please make your example *minimal*?  There is rather a lot of unnecessary creation of pretty graphs, for example.  Simplify the plots. Then simplify and remove some of the latex formatting.  This will allow the real problem to emerge.  At the moment I am just staring at a wall of code, wondering what half of it does.

Comment: @Andrie: I can definitely simplify plots. However, the LaTeX formatting is essential, as the whole idea of this dynamic chunk (template) is to automatically generate narrative's references and matching LaTeX code for a set of R objects (in this case, figures). I will be happy to clarify my LaTeX-related code, if it's too fuzzy.

Comment: @Andrie: I've simplified plotting code. Sorry, but I'm not aware of how to disable displaying plots.

Comment: I don't think your problem is fundamentally about knit chunks.  Try running the code from R interactively, then just before the final chunk evaluate `invisible(sapply(figReportParts, cat));
lapply(figReportParts, function(p) knit(text=p))`.  This is what gets knitted in the final chunk, but it contains errors.  Fix that, and then the rest might fall in place.

Comment: @Andrie: Thank you for the advice. I've already done similar debugging of the original version of this code, but will try again.

Comment: Updated the question upon investigation and fixes.

Comment: Prior to your edits, I thought I knew what you're asking.  Now it's just one blur of text and code intermingled.  I suggest you remove references to "current status" and "updates".  Write the question so it's coherent to anybody reading the question with fresh eyes.  Also, you don't really need all that latex to illustrate the nub of the issue.  Try to make it *minimal*.  PS.  I have been messing about trying to understand what this code does, but not closer to an answer.

Comment: To moderator, who deleted my comment in response to the one above: Please be consistent - either restore my comment, or, if you believe it's not applicable anymore after my update, then please delete the comment above, as it doesn't reflect the current state either.

Comment: What does "MRE" mean?

Comment: @Tripartio **MRE** stands for _minimal reproducible example_. Please see details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example. There are similar answers elsewhere on Stack Exchange, but this should be enough to understand the concept and use it, regardless of programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've figured out what was causing the **issue**. The *first part* was easy. Due to suggested simplification, I've switched from `ggplot2` to standard `R` graphics functions. The problem is that it appears that `plot()` doesn't return a value/object, so that's why NULLs has been seen in the output, instead of plots.

The *second part* was a bit more tricky, but an answer to a related question (https://stackoverflow.com/a/24087398/2872891) clarified the situation. Based on that information, I was able modify my MRE correspondingly and the resulting document appears with correct content (same applies to the generated LaTeX source, which seems to be ready for cross-referencing).

I'm thinking about converting this code into a more generic function for reuse across my project, if time will permit [shouldn't take long] (@Yihui, could this be useful for `knitr` project?). Thanks to everyone who took time to analyze, help or just read this question. I think that `knitr`'s documentation should be more clear on issues, related to producing `PDF` documents from `RMarkdown` source. My **solution** for the MRE follows.

````
---
title: "MRE: a dynamic chunk issue"
author: "Aleksandr Blekh"
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    keep_tex: yes
    highlight: NULL
---

```{r, echo=FALSE, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(ggplot2)

opts_knit$set(progress = F, verbose = F)
opts_chunk$set(comment=NA, warning=FALSE, message=FALSE, echo=FALSE, tidy=FALSE)
```

```{r Preparation, results='hide'}
library(ggplot2)

g1 <- qplot(mpg, wt, data=mtcars)
g2 <- qplot(mpg, hp, data=mtcars)

myPlots <- list(g1, g2)

bcRefStr <- list("objType" = "fig",
                 "objs" = c("g1", "g2"),
                 "str" = "Plots \\ref{fig:g1} and \\ref{fig:g2}")
```

```{r DynamicChunk, include=FALSE}

latexObjLabel <- paste0("{{name}}\\\\label{", bcRefStr$objType, ":{{name}}", "}")

chunkName <- "{{name}}"
chunkHeader <- paste0("```{r ", chunkName, ", ")
chunkOptions <- paste0("include=TRUE, results='asis', fig.height=4, fig.width=4, fig.cap='", latexObjLabel, "'")
chunkHeaderFull <- paste0(chunkHeader, chunkOptions, "}")
chunkBody <- "print(get('{{name}}'))"

chunkText <- c(chunkHeaderFull,
               chunkBody,
               "```", "\n")

figReportParts <- lapply(bcRefStr$objs, function (x) knit_expand(text = chunkText, name = x))
```

`r knit(text = unlist(figReportParts))`
````