# knitr/rmarkdown/Latex: How to cross-reference figures and tables?

Tags: r, latex, knitr, r-markdown, cross-reference

I'm trying to cross-reference figures and tables in a PDF produced with knitr/rmarkdown. There are some questions on SO and tex.stackexchange ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/296010/4762) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31064353/how-to-make-a-figure-caption-in-rmarkdown/31071430#31071430), for example), that suggest the way to do this inline is to add `\ref{fig:my_fig}`, where `my_fig` is the chunk label. However, when I try that in my `rmarkdown` document, I get `??` where the figure number should be. I'd like to find out how to get cross-referencing to work properly.

A reproducible example is below. There are two files: the `rmarkdown` file plus a `header.tex` file that I've included just in case it affects the answer (though I have the same problem whether I include the `header.tex` file or not).

In the `rmarkdown` file there are three cross-reference examples. Example 1 is a figure for which cross-referencing fails (`??` is displayed instead of the figure number). There's also a second, commented-out attempt (based on [this SO answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/296010/4762)), where I try setting the figure environment, label, and caption with `latex` markup before and after the chunk, but this results in a `pandoc` error when I try to knit the document. The error is:

> ```
> ! Missing $ inserted.
> <inserted text> 
>                 $
> l.108 ![](testCrossRef_
> ```

Example 2 uses `xtable` and cross-referencing works. Example 3 uses `kable` and cross-referencing fails.

A screenshot of the PDF output is included at the bottom of this post.

#### `rmarkdown` file

````
---
title: | 
  | My Title  
author: | 
  | eipi10  
  | Department of Redundancy Department  
date: "`r format(Sys.time(), '%B %e, %Y')`"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    includes:
      in_header: header.tex
    keep_tex: yes
fontsize: 11pt
geometry: margin=1in
graphics: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.height=2, fig.width=4)
```

# Example 1. Figure

This is a report. Take a look at Figure \ref{fig:fig1}.  

```{r fig1, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="This is a caption"}
plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg)
```

<!-- Now, let's take a look at this other plot in Figure \ref{fig:fig2}. -->

<!-- \begin{figure} -->
<!-- ```{r fig2, echo=FALSE} -->
<!-- plot(mtcars$cyl, mtcars$mpg) -->
<!-- ``` -->
<!-- \caption{This is another caption} -->
<!-- \label{fig:fig2} -->
<!-- \end{figure} -->

# Example 2: `xtable`

Some more text. See Table \ref{tab:tab1} below. 

```{r echo=FALSE, results="asis"}
library(xtable)
print.xtable(
  xtable(mtcars[1:3,1:4], label="tab:tab1", caption="An xtable table"), 
  comment=FALSE)
```

# Example 3: `kable`

Some more text. See Table \ref{tab:tab2} below. 

```{r tab2, echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
kable(mtcars[1:3,1:4], caption="A `kable` table")
```
````

#### `header.tex` file

```
% Caption on top
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14862/4762
\usepackage{floatrow}
\floatsetup[figure]{capposition=top}
\floatsetup[table]{capposition=top}
```

#### PDF output

[image]

Comment: This issue appears to have been discussed here: [I can't generate \label{fig:mwe-plot} with knitr](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24087398/6455166).  Hard-coding `{r fig1, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="\\label{fig:fig1}This is a caption"}` appears to work.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use the output format `bookdown::pdf_document2` instead of `pdf_document`, and the syntax for referencing a figure is `\@ref(fig:chunk-label)`; see the documentation for details: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/figures.html

Comment: is there a way to do this that is compatible with custom `rmarkdown` formats, e.g. from `rticles` templates?

Comment: @cboettig Yes. Maybe I didn't make it clear enough: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/latexpdf.html You can change `base_format` to whatever output format function in any packages.

Comment: Yihui's [answer above](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38884378/7327356) doesn't seem to work for bookdown::tufte_book2. For a figure cross-reference that shows up correctly with pdf_document2 shows up as "??" when the output format is changed to tufte_book2.

Comment: FYI it seems that one cannot change the base_format for bookdown::pdf_document2 but should use bookdown::pdf_book instead… https://stackoverflow.com/a/52480807/576684

Comment: I'm not sure how to use `pdf_document2` format on an `rmarkdown` file? I only know how to use it with `render_book`. After adding `bookdown::pdf_document2` to the YAML front matter, the option "knit to pdf_document2" appears in RStudio, but otherwise I don't know how from the command line.

Comment: @JamesHirschorn `render_book` is a `bookdown` function, with `rmarkdown` you can use `render` and pass `bookdown::pdf_document2` as `output_format`, e.g. : `rmarkdown::render("Index.Rmd", output_format = bookdown::pdf_document2")`.

Comment: This solves the figure reference isssue, but replaces section numbering by chapter numbering

Answer (score 44):

Following [I can't generate \label{fig:mwe-plot} with knitr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24086498/i-cant-generate-labelfigmwe-plot-with-knitr), adding `\label{...}` to the caption arguments will produce labels in the underlying `tex` file, i.e.

````
```{r fig1, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="\\label{fig:fig1}This is a caption"}
plot(mtcars$wt, mtcars$mpg)
```
````

and

````
```{r tab2, echo=FALSE}
library(knitr)
kable(mtcars[1:3,1:4], caption="\\label{tab:tab2}A `kable` table")
```
````

Comment: @Yihui, since this is based on a [2-year-old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24087398/496488), is this still the state of the art, or are there better ways to do this now?

Comment: There are better ways now. In short, use `bookdown::pdf_document2` instead of `pdf_document`; see https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/figures.html

Comment: This solution has this advantage that it doesn't depend on bookdown.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the [captioner](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/captioner/index.html) package. You can find examples in [this link](https://datascienceplus.com/r-markdown-how-to-number-and-reference-tables/).

In my case, I include a code chunk with:

```
table_captions <- captioner::captioner(prefix="Tab.")
figure_captions <- captioner::captioner(prefix="Fig.")

t.ref <- function(label){
  stringr::str_extract(table_captions(label), "[^:]*")
}

f.ref <- function(label){
  stringr::str_extract(figure_captions(label), "[^:]*")
}
```

I include captions in tables and figures when defining code chunks, like this:

````
```{r chunk_creating_one_figure, echo=FALSE, fig.cap=figure_captions("one_figure", "figure label")}
plot(1)
```
````

or

````
```{r chunk_creating_one_table, echo=FALSE, fig.cap=table_captions("one_table", "table label")}
knitr::kable(data.frame(col="something"), format="markdown")
```
````

References are included as inline_text all across my Rmarkdown with:

```
As shown in figure `r f.ref("one_figure")`
Data is shown on table `r t.ref("one_table")`
```

Comment: Here we are in April 2022 and I still can't find an answer to the question of how to reference a figure in the caption of another figure using bookdown::tufte_book2. I've tried every suggestion I can find for the past 6 years and nothing seems to work. Does anyone know of a definitive guide to doing this? Here's what I'm trying to do

```{r Fig608,echo=F,fig.fullwidth=T,fig.show='hold',fig.width=5.5,warning=F, message=F,fig.asp=0.35,fig.cap='New plot title from \\label{fig:Fig607}'}

in which Fig607 is previously defined in a chunk. The result is the caption ends with 'from '.

Answer (score 1):

After much searching I stumbled on a solution that seems to work ([link for this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33284343/knitr-can-i-cite-an-article-in-a-figure-caption-using-the-fig-cap-chunk-option)), even though I never found it in any of the bookdown standard references (I'll keep looking). Just above the chunk that creates the plot in the .rmd file, define the caption as a string, here called "crossref2" and put the Figure reference in the string in the normal way, `\@ref(fig:myChunkLabel)`. No quotes are needed. Here's an example where Fig207 is the chunk label for the figure being referenced:

```
(ref:crossref2) Variations on boxplot using data from Figure \@ref(fig:Fig207) a) plain violin plot, b) enchanced violin plot, c) add outliers, d) Beeswarm plot
```

Then in the chunk header for the figure where you want Fig207 to be included in the caption, the figure caption is written as

```
fig.cap='(ref:crossref2)'
```

After doing this, the Figure number connected to ref(fig:Fig207) is displayed nicely in the caption.

Note that the same procedure allows you to put a bibliography reference in a figure caption by replacing `\@ref(fig:Fig207)` with `[@bibref]` where bibref is the keyword for the reference as defined in your .bib file of literature citations.