# No citations in PDF without manually editing the generated .tex file

Tags: r-markdown, bookdown, citations

I'm trying to get my publications into R-Markdown, specifically by using the `rticles` package, but I'm running into problems with citations. 
The goal is to get the natbib option running, such that citations are not "hardcoded" by pandoc.

I am familiar with the following topic on this website and references therein, but this does *not* provide a solution:
[natbib-seems-to-not-work-properly-with-pdf-book-rticles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42378269/natbib-seems-to-not-work-properly-with-pdf-book-rticles)

Whenever I 'knit' the article while using the `natbib` option my references remain undefined.
The only solution I was able to find was through the `keep_tex: true` option and adding the `\bibliography` command manually after compilation. 
I can not imagine that this is really required to make the citations functional.

What I've tried, and the best I could come up with is the following modification of the template provided by `rticles` is posted below. 
The only way I found to get it running is actually open the generated `.tex` file and before the `\end{document}` add the line `\bibliography{mybibfile}`, which can not be as intended.

Can anyone reproduce my issue and am I simply missing something, or is the issue more on the package side?

```
---
title: Short Paper
author:
  - name: Alice Anonymous
    email: alice@example.com
    affiliation: Some Institute of Technology
    footnote: Corresponding Author
address:
  - code: Some Institute of Technology
    address: Department, Street, City, State, Zip
journal: "An awesome journal"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
bibliography: mybibfile.bib
output: 
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    citation_package: natbib
    base_format: rticles::elsevier_article
    number_sections: yes
    keep_tex: true
---

Bibliography styles
===================

Here are two sample references: @Feynman1963118 [@Dirac1953888].

References {#references .unnumbered}
==========
```

with the following `mybibfile.bib`:

```
@article{Dirac1953888,
  title   = "The lorentz transformation and absolute time",
  journal = "Physica ",
  volume  = "19",
  number  = "1-–12",
  pages   = "888--896",
  year    = "1953",
  doi     = "10.1016/S0031-8914(53)80099-6",
  author  = "P.A.M. Dirac"
}

@article{Feynman1963118,
  title   = "The theory of a general quantum system interacting with a linear dissipative system",
  journal = "Annals of Physics ",
  volume  = "24",
  pages   = "118--173",
  year    = "1963",
  doi     = "10.1016/0003-4916(63)90068-X",
  author  = "R.P Feynman and F.L {Vernon Jr.}"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes reference section does not appear due to that no bibliography style is specified when knitting PDF via LaTeX from RMarkdown. According to [the official document](https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/citations.html), you can set `biblio-style` in the YAML section like this:

```
bibliography: mybibfile.bib
biblio-style: apa #whatever style you want
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the `\bibliography{mybibfile}` at the end of the rmd file works as well.