# Cross referencing figures in tufte_html

Tags: html, r, knitr, bookdown, tufte

I am building a `tufte::tufte_html` which should contain cross references to a figure. Unlucky me, I've been trying for a whole day for no avail.

Below, I also try with what has been suggested for `bookdown` version of [`pdf_document2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38884378/6725057). Any offerings of advice would be precious here.

````
---
title: "Repro cross-referencing"
subtitle: "A how to guide"
author: "Deependra Dhakal"
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output:
  tufte::tufte_html: default
link-citations: yes
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(tufte)
# invalidate cache when the tufte version changes
knitr::opts_chunk$set(tidy = FALSE, cache.extra = packageVersion('tufte'))
options(htmltools.dir.version = FALSE)
```

# Introduction

This is just an example

```{r examp-fig, fig.width=10, fig.cap="\\label{fig:examp-fig}Not a good caption"}

plot(2:5, 5:8)
```


## Try referencing here

Through the figure [@fig:examp-fig], I am trying to demonstrate how cross referencing works. But apparently this doesn't work.

Is this any better? The figure \@ref(fig:examp-fig) is being referenced here. Naaah!
````

Answer (score 0):

You can use bookdown package. In this case you have to add the following "output" option in your yaml preamble:

```
output:
  bookdown::tufte_html2: default
```

This should work I think!