# Can't use PLOS rticles template with bookdown

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

Following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38884378/576684), I'm trying to put @YihuiXie 's answer in practice with the PLOS template of rticles but it doesn't work. Any help would be very appreciated!

Below in a minimal example:

```
---
title: Title of submission to PLOS journal
author:
  - name: Me
    affiliation: Here

# output: rticles::plos_article
output:
  bookdown::pdf_document2:
    base_format: rticles::plos_article
---

# Introduction

Some text \@ref(fig:fig1)

# References {#references .unnumbered}
```

The error message reads

```
Error in pdf_book(..., base_format = rmarkdown::pdf_document) :    formal argument "base_format" matched by multiple actual arguments 
Calls: <Anonymous> -> create_output_format -> do.call -> <Anonymous> 
Execution halted
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot change the `base_format` for `bookdown::pdf_document2`. You can do so for `bookdown::pdf_book`, though:

```
---
title: Title of submission to PLOS journal
author:
  - name: Me
    affiliation: Here

#output: rticles::plos_article
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book:
    base_format: rticles::plos_article
---

# Introduction

Some text \@ref(fig:fig1)

# References {#references .unnumbered}
```

Note to other readers: Make sure that `.../rticles/rmarkdown/templates/plos_article/skeleton/PLOS-submission.eps` is present in that directory.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I just added a comment in the initial thread for future readers.